# Image is not showing in django template but other tag is working

Tags: django

I am trying to show up my image in django template. But the image is not showing. There is a headline tag which is working fine. I don't know where I am stuck. I searched it here and got a lot of solution, but none of this are not solving my issue.

Here is my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from django.utils import timezone

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.order_by('id')

    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Here is my urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from Picture import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And this is home.html:

```
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>{{ posts.title }}</h1>
    <img src="{{ posts.image.url }}" alt="image-{{ post.title }}">
</body>
```

Images are in the media directory. Please help me to fix my problem.

Comment: @Sharif, I think you should help us help you. If you paste your code and make us go from one site to other it's kind of unfare!... Please copy the important parts of your code in your question. Then you'll probably receive answers more quickly!.

Comment: Is it only your image not showing or everything else?

Comment: @BidhanMajhi only image not showing

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems with your code

1. `return render(request, 'home.html')` does not have posts context parameter
2. In your template file `posts` object is likely to be a queryset, you need to loop through it to render its properties

> ```
> def home(request):
>     posts = Post.objects.order_by('id')
>     return render(request, 'home.html', {"posts":posts})
> ```

Comment: I have changes the template and view file. But still the image are not showing.
Template file is:
`<body>
 {% for post in posts %}
  <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
  <img src="{{ post.image.url }}" alt="image-{{ post.title }}">
 {% endfor %}
</body>`